# How to copy lots of files between two computers, without network?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, file-transfer

I want to copy around 50Gb of files from my desktop to my work laptop. For some reason, the laptop won't connect to my home network. I haven't had any luck with a direct ethernet connection either, and I'm not willing to change any of the laptop's network configuration (last time I did that, I couldn't get onto the network at work, making me Not Very Popular).

So...what else is there? The obvious route is copying via SD card. My largest card is 8Gb. But I can't find a good workflow. Is there a tool designed for this, where I could just repetitively move the card back and forth, without having to select files? I've tried using teracopy, but you end up missing a few files. I guess I *could* zip everything up into multi-volume .rars or something...but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: 50 Gb or 50 GiB? If you have 50 Gb, one or two DVDs would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help: [PC To PC USB Cable](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?pkc=AFgZ2tmAzzvQWloRaHJLQ9hPsATS5D5O1BVSTW997buMLhjvEYuRGLrwC6rH1bXQXgtTrOmp0o3A3LcKl-qL8CBGsXxeKEwyQw&cid=2203750877355603953#)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the simplest and cheapest way to go.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably worth investing a few bucks in getting an external (USB) hard drive.

You can get quite a high capacity (say 500GB or so) for well under $100, and as well as allowing you to transfer all your data in one go, you could also use it for backing up your data for safe keeping.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try a [USB cable](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/248).

If a [straight-through](http://www.pingjeffgreene.com/archive/2009/06/how-to-make-your-own-ethernet-network-cables/t-568b-straight-through-ethernet-cable) ethernet cable failed, you might want to try a [cross-over](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) cable instead

Comment: I use a cross-over cable, but the issues were to do with subnets and windows networking. (ie, just because there is a physical connection doesn't solve all your problems)

Answer (score 0):

come on how can you not configure a simple network?...plug an rj45 cable between the 2 pc an then assign statics ips. For example give to your notebook the 10.10.10.1 and your desktop the 10.10.10.2.
Give both the same mask 255.255.255.0.

To reestablish the order active the dhcp in both adapters after you finish.

Execute this lines in a console as administrator (Powershell or CMD) without the comments (//...):

```
netsh interface ip set address "ConnectionNameHere" static 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0 //in the laptop 
netsh interface ip set address "ConnectionNameHere" static 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.0 //in the desktop
```

Reestablish the order:

```
netsh interface ip set address "ConnectionNameHere" dhcp //in both pc...(asumming that you connect directly)
```

pd: don't forget that learn something is more cheap than buy any gadgets

Comment: Heh, I appreciate your enthusiasm. It's just a risk I'm willing to take though. If it was two personal computers, I probably would. I have actually studied networking before. Maybe I could get it to work. Who knows.

Oh, and the bigger problem was actually getting the other computer to show up in "my network places".

Comment: @SteveBennett dont use "my network places", instead access the computer shares using explorer putting in the address this: \\ComputerIPADDRESS\ShareName. For example if you want to see desktop shares from your laptop open explorer and put \\10.10.10.2\Sharename. Sharename is whatever the desktop is sharing, could be a folder a printer or other device.

Comment: @SteveBennett is frequent that "my network places" fail to show all the pc in the net. For that reason use the ip not the computer name, \\Ipaddress\share <--alwayswork, \\computername\share <--sometimes work, its an innerent problem of the name translation. If you use always the ip you are not going to have any problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)? If the company allows it, probably Dropbox is a good way to move files between computers with minimal hassle. In addition, you don't have to bring your laptop to office, since it will sync the folder automatically in both directions.

You'll get about 2GB for free and after that you'll need to pay for subscription.

Comment: I do use and adore dropbox. However, in Australia we have limited data usage per month. Doing that would wipe out most of my month's quota.

(I seem to recall dropbox adding a feature where it could transfer directly across lan...but that's not going to help me.)